# attempt to find a semi-colon before the property name. add it

Tags: css, w3c-validation, vendor-prefix

First post...

On running a *W3C* scan on some `CSS` I get the error above. Plus two others.

Errors: LINE 30 is flagged as the cause?

1. `attempt to find a semi-colon before the property name. add it`
2. `Property progid doesn't exist :  MXtransform`
3. `Parse Error  MXtransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');`

*hopefully I have posted this correctly apologies if not, first post.*

**CSS**

---

```
.checkLink {

    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop  (1, #dfdfdf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
```

*LINE 30 this line is flagging as wrong*

```
filter:progid:MXtransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');

    background-color:#ededed;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
```

---

*Also there are some warnings*

> "Property -moz-box-shadow is an unknown vendor extension" AND 
>   -webkit-box-shadow

Why are these both flagged as unknown extensions?

Any pointers greatly appreciated, I have done some searches but got conflicting information and my experience - so far is lacking.

Comment: You should specify which “W3C scan” you are referring to. Apparently it is http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator

Answer (score 5):

Your CSS code uses the nonstandard Microsoft invention `filter:progid:MXtransform.Microsoft.gradient`, which, in addition to not being defined in any CSS specification, violates generic CSS syntax. Therefore the W3C CSS validator issues an error message about it even at the parsing level. There is no way around this: if you wish to use the feature, you will get the error messages.

“Unknown vendor extensions” are nonstandard, and therefore warnings are issued. But they are just warnings, and if you wish to have CSS code working on browsers that do not yet support the standard property names, you need to have the vendor-prefixed properties, too. For example, for [`box-shadow`](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow), the `-moz-` prefixed version is needed in order to cover Firefox versions 3.6 to 15 (probably with combined usage share below 1%).

Comment: Thank you, most helpful. Mr Gates has a lot to answer for.